# type Array has no field args for simple property in julia QuickCheck

Tags: julia

I'm trying to use the [Julia programming language](http://julialang.org/) for the first time, specifically I'm trying to write a simple example using the [QuickCheck](https://quickcheckjl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package. Here is the code:

```
module QuickCheckTest

using QuickCheck


function factorial(n)
  if n < 0
    error("factorial undefined for negative numbers")
  end
  if 0 <= n <= 2
    n
  else
    n*factorial(n-1)
  end
end

property((n::Int)->factorial(n)/n == factorial(n-1))

end
```

When I run this using Julia 0.2.0 on my windows 7 machine I get the following error:

```
ERROR: type Array has no field args
 in lambda_arg_types at C:\Users\Bas\Documents\Dropbox\.julia\QuickCheck\src\Qui
ckCheck.jl:16
 in property at C:\Users\Bas\Documents\Dropbox\.julia\QuickCheck\src\QuickCheck.
jl:26
 in include at boot.jl:238
 in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:114
WARNING: backtraces on your platform are often misleading or partially incorrect
```

I feel the above code is similar to the one used in the [QuickCheck documentation](https://quickcheckjl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). The [QuickCheck](https://quickcheckjl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) version I'm using is 0.0.0. I have searched the internet but can not find any useful information. Can anyone give me any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong here?

### Update:

Apparently this was a bug in [QuickCheck](https://quickcheckjl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), this bug has now been fixed.

Comment: You should file a bug report on the QuickCheck repository.

Comment: @Isaiah: done, [issue 3](https://github.com/pao/QuickCheck.jl/issues/3), thanks for looking at my code.

Comment: Definitely a bug. Thanks!

Comment: This question is actually a bug in the mentioned library. This was unclear when the question was opened. Now this is clear and this question should be closed.

Comment: For future visitors, it should be noted that this bug has now been fixed.